# How do Valas closures map to Genie?

Tags: lambda, closures, vala, genie

The [Vala Tutorial](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/Tutorial) has an [example about DBus using anonymous methods](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/Tutorial#line-13-26).

```
Bus.own_name (BusType.SESSION, "org.example.DemoService", /* name to register */
              BusNameOwnerFlags.NONE, /* flags */
              on_bus_aquired, /* callback function on registration succeeded */
              () => {}, /* callback on name register succeeded */
              () => stderr.printf ("Could not acquire name\n")); /* callback on name lost */
```

I am trying to rewrite this code in Genie, but could not manage to convert the two last lines. The [Genie Tutorial](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Genie) only has [an example on how to use a closure to define an event handler](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Genie#line-7-10).

```
f.my_event += def (t, a)
    print "event was detected with value %d", a
```

How do I use anonymous method definitions in a method call with Genie?

Answer (score 4):

I think there is not way. You must call another process using "def".

```
Bus.own_name (BusType.SESSION, "org.example.DemoService", 
          BusNameOwnerFlags.NONE, 
          on_bus_aquired, 
          reg,
          err);

def reg()
    pass

def err()
    print "error"
```

Answer (score 4):

This isn't possible at the moment:

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=746704

> Currently Genie only support the deprecated lambda syntax for signals
>   (+=). This patch provides lambda support in most constructs, the only
>   requirement is that braces and parens need to be indent-balanced on
>   multiple line constructs.