# How to connect() an anonymous handler to an event in Genie?

Tags: vala, gobject, genie

Guides and samples seem to tell you to use the `+=` operator to add handlers to GObject events. E.g. "[A brief guide](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Genie#Events)" and Gtk tutorials.

```
f.my_event += def (t, a)
    print "event was detected with value %d", a
```

The compiler complains about this:

```
$ valac events.gs
events.gs:8.5-12.5: warning: deprecated syntax, use `connect' method instead
Compilation succeeded - 1 warning(s)
```

If `+=` is deprecated, is there a way to do this with connect inline without creating a named method and using connect with that? Was this ever intended to work or is the warning just a style tip in the wrong place?

Google does turn up a few mailing list postings with no apparent answers.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24352222/how-do-valas-closures-map-to-genie

Comment: I marked duplicate as the other question seems to have an answer now saying only += is supported despite deprecation.